# Stream audio using ionic and phonegap will it make compression?

Tags: streaming, ionic-framework

If I use Ionic framework and phonegap to build a streaming app, will those technologies make any compression on the audio I'm streaming? I have some wav files I need to stream, and there must be no compression at all.

Best regards
Rasmus Christensen

Comment: wav files may already be compressed, but I am guessing you mean no more compression. If you are building the app yourself you can decide whether or not to compress your files, so you should not have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is no, no compression. I've been using the Cordova Media plugin for a while. I developed an app that streams mp3 files from Amazon Cloudfront.
On the other hand this might not be real streaming but progressive download. 
Here's the plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/